# watir after form submit

Tags: ruby, webdriver, watir, watir-webdriver

I am new to WATIR+Ruby.
I am trying to continue to test after logging into a form like this

```
browser.link(:name, 'login-facebook id=').click
browser.text_field(:id,'email').set(usr)
browser.text_field(:id,'pass').set(pwd)
puts 'form submit'
browser.form(:id,'login_form').submit
puts 'hello world'
```

upto login works. I see form submit and form is submitted. But can't go further. Don't see 'hello world'

Comment: for whichever domain, you can review the robots.txt file to see their policy on automation. https://www.facebook.com/robots.txt

Comment: Is there a user available control to submit the form? Perhaps the submit button does more than just submitting the form (ie calls some other functions first)?

Answer (score 4):

I think what's causing the problem here is the http request which is taking some time to load, try putting something like

```
sleep 1 until b.a(:class, "jewelButton").exists?
```

right below your 5th line.

Also why not: `b.button(:text, "Log In").click` instead of `b.form(:id,'login_form').submit` ?

In irb it works fine either way:

```
irb(main):001:0>require "watir-webdriver"
=> true
irb(main):002:0>b = Watir::Browser.new :chrome
Started ChromeDriver
port=55320
version=22.0.1203.0b
log=C:\Users\your_username\chromedriver.log
=> #<Watir::Browser:0x..fc4b0180c url="chrome://newtab/" title="New Tab">
irb(main):015:0> b.goto "facebook.com"
=> "http://www.facebook.com/"
irb(main):003:0>b.text_field(:id,'email').set(usr)
=> {}
irb(main):004:0>b.text_field(:id,'pass').set(pwd)
=> {}
irb(main):005:0>puts 'form submit'
form submit
=> nil
irb(main):006:0>b.button(:text,"Log In").click
=> nil
irb(main):007:0>puts "blah blah"
blah blah
=> nil
irb(main):008:0>b.a(:class, "jewelButton").click
=> []
irb(main):010:0>b.a(:class, "jewelButton").click
=> []
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you use new lines for all commands (unlike the block of code you pasted), my first thought is that the console will not display text output until the end of the test unless you have buffer sync turned on.  Is it possible you're not waiting for the script to finish?

Add this line to the top of your script and see if that resolves the issue.

```
$stdout.sync = true
browser.link(:name, 'login-facebook id=').click
browser.text_field(:id,'email').set(usr)
browser.text_field(:id,'pass').set(pwd)
puts 'form submit'
browser.form(:id,'login_form').submit
puts 'hello world'
```

Comment: You are only bound by a ToS if you accept it. Automating a facebook login imho is perfectly reasonable.

Comment: It is just for testing my multi auth and comes back to the page and test some more. $stdout.sync = true didn't do any magic. THanks

Comment: If "form submit" displays correctly, there is no reason with this code that "hello world" would not also display unless the script breaks during the submit action and does not continue...

Comment: No, action is working fine. I can see the sign in link becomes Sign out link. Something wrong with the code. May be i am not explaining it right

Comment: Well, the browser source or a link to the page would be helpful in that case.  As it is presented, there should be no reason for this to fail unless the script breaks before or at the submit action.